# npm weird error 135 on using npm start

Tags: node.js, npm, ghost-blog

I am installing [Ghost](https://ghost.org) and while installing it I followed the following steps at:

http://docs.ghost.org/installation/linux/

But on running `npm start` I get the following errors:

```
> node index
Bus error (core dumped)
npm ERR! weird error 135
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

What should I do? I am a newbie to node or npm

Comment: Does it literally say `weird error 135`?

Comment: @RUJordan it does. I have copied and pasted the exact error from my terminal.

Comment: Wow that is possibly the worst described error I've ever seen. I'll do some searching to try and help

Comment: [read this](https://ghost.org/forum/installation/1129-npm-err-weird-error-137/), [and this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/338268-getting-errors-when-setting-up-and-starting-nodejs-server/) and see if the discussion helps you out, it sounds like it's an environment issue, not a ghost issue.

Comment: Hi @RUJordan its working. I still don't know the reason for error 135. But I just made another folder for it and ran `npm install --production` and then `npm start` and it worked. I guess the problem was that some of the files were not downloaded correctly. Since your link guided me to the answer, would you like to write it is an answer so that I can select it as the correct answer.

Comment: Sure thing, I'll do that now.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](https://ghost.org/forum/installation/1129-npm-err-weird-error-137/), and [this also](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/338268-getting-errors-when-setting-up-and-starting-nodejs-server/), there is most likely an environment issue such as an improperly or missing file or configuration setting. Trying in a new, fresh installed environment should fix this issue.